# Duplicate files copied in APK Error

Tags: java, android

First off, Ive researched the forms and found many topics covering this. However, I have attempted all options that I found and nothing seems to work. Here is the error:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK org/codehaus/jackson/impl/VERSION.txt

File1: C:\Users\Austin\AndroidStudioProjects\Intelwatch\app\libs\jackson-core-asl-1.8.5.jar

File2: C:\Users\Austin\AndroidStudioProjects\Intelwatch\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.esri.arcgis.android\arcgis-android\10.2.7\jars\libs\jackson-core-1.9.5.jar

**app build.gradle:**

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.f0xcr4f7.intelwatch"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions{
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/VERSION'
        exclude 'META-INF/VERSION.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/version.txt'
     }
    }

    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar', '.so'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.esri.arcgis.android:arcgis-android:10.2.7'
    compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.3.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-core-asl-1.8.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/KumulosAndroid.0.2.3.jar')
    }
```

Comment: where is `jackson-core-1.9.5.jar`?

Comment: I traced the location of it and Kumulos has me place it inside of the "libs" folder while ArcGIS has it using "maven". They are both separate companies and use the same libraries? Does that mean I can just dump the one in the "lib" folder and keep the maven one?

Comment: @F0xcr4f7 any solution?